# Will onUpgrade be called for each increment?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Assume i have my app's database version 1 running on some user device for a while.

in the meantime i increment database version to 2, and then to 3 and handle onUpgrade like that :

```
if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2) {
                db.execSQL(String.format("ALTER TABLE ... ADD .. text", ));

            } else if (oldVersion == 2 && newVersion == 3) {
                 db.execSQL(String.format("ALTER TABLE ... ADD .. text", ));
            }
```

When that user upgrades my app, will both blocks be executed?

Comment: No, the version is defined in the SQLite database.  If they upgrade from an APK that has 1 to an APK that has 3, then neither will fire.

Comment: @JaySnayder so im gonna have to handle each possibility out of "n choose 2" possibilities explicitly? thats stupid...

Comment: You can just have one case and rebuild your database each time.  Perhaps you can clarify what you are trying to achieve with the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you can use:

```
if (oldVersion == 1) {
  do stuff;
  oldVersion = oldVersion + 1;
}

if (oldVersion == 2) {
  do stuff;
  oldVersion = oldVersion + 1;
}
```

or use a switch.

Comment: is anybody using this solution? just want to ask before using it